# meteor.js - pass id of element clicked to a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor, meteor-helper

I've built a page with 3 elements, each of which looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 event-type">
<a href="{{ pathFor 'step2' }}" id="eventchoice" name="eventchoice" value="corporate">
</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to pass the value or name or id of the the `<a>` element on to a collection using the following code:

```
EventsController.events({
    'click #eventchoice' : function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.getAttribute("id"));
        console.log(event.target.getAttribute("name"));
        console.log(event.target.getAttribute("value"));

        var eventchoice = event.target.value;   
        var params = {
            eventchoice: eventchoice 
        }

        //Insert Event
        Meteor.call('addEvent', params);
        FlashMessages.sendSuccess('Event Added');
    }
});
```

I added the console.log's to see if I can get the id/name/value of the `<a>` element, but the console outputs 'null' for all of these. Therefore, there is nothing to pass to the collection in the eventAdd method.

I don't believe the problem is with the EventsController, the addEvent method or the Events collection. Any ideas how I can pass these values through?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there must be something wrong with your controller then, because if you check the [Meteorpad here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/anBN5BiLycb9L2hth/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard%20(1)), it works just fine.
Although you might want to use a class instead of an id if you have many similar elements.

Comment: Actually the issue was that for some reason the selector was targeting the child element (i.e. the <img> contained within the <a>), so I fixed this by using event.target.alt. I had excluded that from the code above for simplicity's sake. Nonetheless, you are right that there also was a problem with the controller, now fixed. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways of solving your problem but the way I consider as "The Meteor Way" is to use a separate template for every choice (or just use #each loop), if you do that your "this" inside the event code will contain the values you need in your scope, so you won't have to rely on the event.target for them.